# MVC 5 referencing unmanaged dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unmanagedresources

I am struggling with an issue and am utterly lost as to the correct approach to handle the problem.

I have an MVC 5 application running on Windows Server 2008 R2 that communicates with an accounting package (Exchequer) via an unmanaged COM dll. As I understand it (and I'm not sure I do) the unmanaged dll is created once per app domain? Meaning that multiple users of the app will all be 'using' the same unmanaged instance? Ideally, I would want one instance of the COM dll to be created and destroyed per user. Can anyone please tell me if this is possible and, if so, how I would go about implementing it? Thanks

Comment: No, unmanaged code is loaded in the process outside of the appdomain. This means that unloading a appdomain does not automatically release the unmanaged memory of the loaded unmanaged code. `Ideally, I would want one instance of the COM dll to be created and destroyed per user` <= maybe you can get a better answer to this if you explain why you would want to do this and how you will be using the dll (methods).

Comment: Thanks Igor. I haven't explained very well. Sorry. What I actually want is one instance of a class within the COM dll to be created per user. It seems to be shared. The reason I say 'seems to be' is that we are getting errors stating that an instance of a class (called toolkit) is already in use when trying to instantiate it. I know very little about COM, I'm afraid, so I don't know if this is specific to the design of this particular dll or something that is common to all unmanaged dlls?

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I have just found this in the documentation:The COM Toolkit (DLL) is an In-Process COM Object and because of this it can only support a single client application (or DLL) at a time per process, this is because all the applications and libraries within the same process see the same instance of the COM Toolkit DLL, including all its global variables